# Trouble with deep copy in copy constructor

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create deep copy of instance of my class via copy constructor, but I can't figure out, how to write it.. In this moment, When I call copy constructor, the programm doesn't crash, nevertheless when I want to do anything with the instances (ie print the array, add some item to it, etc.) then the programme crashes...

Could anybody please show me, how to write it properly? It's driving me crazy yet O_o

```
struct DbChange {
    const char* date;
    const char* street;
    const char* city;
};

class DbPerson {
public:
    DbPerson(void);
    const char* id;
    const char* name;
    const char* surname;
    DbChange * change;
    int position;
    int size;
};

DbPerson::DbPerson() {
    position = 0;
    size = 1000;
    change = new DbChange[1000];
}

class Register {
public:
    // default constructor
    Register(void);

    int size;
    int position;
    DbPerson** db;

    //copy constructor
    Register(const Register& other) : db() {    
        db=  new DbPerson*[1000];       
        std::copy(other.db, other.db + (1000), db);      
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Register a;
    /*
     * put some items to a
     */

    Register b ( a );

    a . Print (); // now crashes
    b . Print (); // when previous line is commented, then it crashes on this line...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your space bar/tab key? Also `Register(void);` should be `Register();`

Comment: Can you say `std::string` boys and girls? I knew you could!

Comment: Have you tried `a.Print()` without creating instance of b? Maybe problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I can, nevertheless I mustn't ;) This is a part of my homework, where we mustn't use strings...don't ask me why O_o...

Comment: @PiotrJaszkowski Yep..I did and it works well...

Comment: Are you sure you are inserting 1000 elements?

Comment: @Dworza: If you can't use `std::string` write a small imitation of your own that handles the subset of operations you need, then use that in the other classes. Likewise, you really seem to need/want `std::vector` (again, if you can't use the one in the standard library, write a stripped-down version of your own).

Comment: No - 1000 is top value and I will optimize it yet - this is just for testing. And I really don't understand how could this ruin printing out of `a`

Comment: @Dworza so if `a.db` contains less than 1000 elements you are copying something undefined to `b.db`. Besides that how can we say why `Print` crashes without seeing it?

Comment: Well...@sehe got it...I forgot to copy `position` value thus I tried to print out some NULL values and thus it crashed... Oh god...I'm really ashamed now! :D

Comment: Nevertheless I still don't understand how is possible, that I couldn't even print out `a`...that shouldn't be affected by it, or should?

Comment: When do you ever initialize position?

Comment: Style comment: prefer initialization lists to member assignment in constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the code shown in no way allows us to guess what Print does, and why it chashes, I'll just show you how I'd expect things to be in C++ (instead of an awkward mix between C and Java):

**[http://liveworkspace.org/code/4ti5TS$0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4ti5TS%240)**

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct DbChange {
    std::string date;
    std::string street;
    std::string city;
};

class DbPerson {
    public:
        DbPerson(void);

        std::string id, name, surname;
        int position;
        std::vector<DbChange> changes;

        size_t size() const { return changes.size(); }
};

DbPerson::DbPerson() : position(), changes() { }

class Register {
    public:
        size_t size() const { return db.size(); }
        int position; // unused?
        std::vector<DbPerson> db;

        Register() = default;

        //copy constructor
        Register(const Register& other) : db(other.db) 
        { 
            // did you forget to copy position? If so, this would have been the
            // default generated copy constructor
        }

        void Print() const
        {
            // TODO
        }
};


int main() {
    Register a;
    /*
     * put some items to a
     */

    Register b(a);

    a.Print(); // now crashes
    b.Print(); // when previous line is commented, then it crashes on this line...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Print is written well, so there should be no problem - Before calling copyconstructor printing works well... And as you can see in comments under my post, I'm very limited on includes, thus I use these weird constructions.... ehm...and yes...I'm also longtime java programmer :D

Comment: Print will probably do something with the unitialized pointers in `DbPersion::change` or `Register::db`. No matter how well written it is, that will always be undefined behaviour

Comment: Oh TY! That goddamn position! :D I've been searching this bug for hours and didn't notice, that I didn't copy position value, thus I tried to access NULL values in other functions and thus the program crashed :)) Sometimes we don't see things that are really obvious... Haha...I feel ashamed a little bit now :D